# Getting undefined for something that I didn't declare

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I have a `factory` in which I set a IP which is common for all controllers. I get the ip in the other controllers and add the web service method like this: `url : $scope.ipForHttp+"getDeviceDetailsReport"` where `$scope.ipForHttp` is `http://websitename.com/` which I get from the `factory`.

This works in my local computer. When I host this and open the page I get it the first time for all pages. But when I refresh the page I see an error in console.

`GET http://websitename.com/undefinedgetDeviceDetailsReport 404 (Not Found)`. I get this error only when I refresh the page and only in the hosted site, not in my local computer.

I'm getting `undefined` between the `/` and method name `getDeviceDetailsReport`.

This is some of the code where I use the data from `factory`:

```
$scope.ipForHttp = userDetailsFactory.getUserDetailsFromFactory().ipAddress;
$scope.loading = false;
$scope.ClientID = userDetailsFactory.getUserDetailsFromFactory().clientidFromSession;
// $scope.dev={};
$scope.getDevice =function(){
    $scope.loading = true;
      $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : $scope.ipForHttp+"getDeviceDetailsReport" //i think undefined error here.
```

And I'm getting this `Error: ngRepeat:dupes
Duplicate Key in Repeater` too only when I refresh the page.

**Edit**. I run the `factory` and set the value every time the page is refreshed. Maybe the value is `undefined` the second time..but I don't know how I still have the old value.

Maybe this is why I get the `Error: ngRepeat:dupes` when I refresh too. What am I doing wrong?

The index page's(which contains the other html pages)  controller with the `factory`:

```
    angular.module('tollApp')
.controller('indexController', function($scope,$http,$window,userDetailsFactory){
    $scope.usernameFromServer={};
    $scope.getUserDetails = function(){
        $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:'http://192.168.1.80:4000/getUserDetails'
            // url:'http://websitename.com/getUserDetails'
        })
        .then(function(response){

            // console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            userDetailsFactory.setUserDetailsInFactory(response.data);
        $scope.usernameFromFactory = userDetailsFactory.getUserDetailsFromFactory().usernameFromSession;
        $scope.theIP = userDetailsFactory.getUserDetailsFromFactory().ipAddress;
            // $scope.usernameFromServer = userDetailsFactory.getUserDetailsFromFactory().username;
            // console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.usernameFromFactory)+"usernameFromFactory");
        })
    }
    $scope.logout = function(request,response){
        $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:'/logout'
        })
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            if(response.data=="logout"){
                // $window.location.href="http://websitename.comlogin";
                $window.location.href="http://192.168.1.80:4000/login";

            }
        })
    }
    console.log("indexController");
}).factory('userDetailsFactory',function(){
    var user = {};
    return {
        setUserDetailsInFactory : function(val){
            user.useridFromSession = val[0].UserID;
            user.usernameFromSession = val[0].UserName;
            user.userroleFromSession = val[0].UserRole;
            user.clientidFromSession = val[0].ClientID;
             user.ipAddress = "http://192.168.1.80:4000/";
            // user.ipAddress = "http://websitename.com/";
            // console.log("in set "+user.clientidFromSession);
        },
        getUserDetailsFromFactory : function(){
            return user;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: whrere you are using ng-repeat, that has a duplicate key, use `track by $index` to resolve it first.

Comment: @Sravan. what about first problem. also see edit

Comment: you might have appending the value, instead of replacing it , please add the factory code.

Comment: I am sorry was little busy, now checking it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126895/discussion-between-sravan-and-iliveinapineappleunderthesea).

Comment: I am also there in chat room.

Answer (score 0):

That error is because you are doing an ng-repeat on a collection with duplicates. You need to track by index when you are doing an ng-repeat on a collection with duplicates.